# Eclipse RCP: Change startpage of help page

Tags: eclipse-rcp

How do I set the startpage when the user opens the help pages?

I added my personal help pages to my application which I can browse without an issue via extending `org.eclipse.help.toc`.
Now I want to change the start-help-page that the user sees when opening the help page. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the start page of the help pages you have to do the following:

1. Extend org.eclipse.core.runtime.products.
2. Add your product.
3. Add a property.
4. Define a property file and fill with the following
   content: org.eclipse.help.base/help_home=\ /pluginfolder+pathToHtml

This also works if there are help files with different languages available.